# Open mail app on android without new message

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, email

I need to open the mail app from a cordova app, something like (iOS):

`window.open('message://')`

This open iOS mail client without create a new email view, just the all mail that i received.

It's possible do the same thing in Android (with javascript of course)?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: This : "It's possible do the same thing in Android (with javascript of course)?"

Comment: Maybe with intents you can.